# Magento product.create websites argument

Tags: api, magento, soap

I have a question about the websites argument in the magento api.

Nowhere can I find an explanation of what this variable is.
Does this variable represent a storeview? a store? a website?

Where in the api can I retrieve a list of available options?

If I cannot retrieve a list from the API, where in the backend menu can I find the static variable that I can use?
Do I need the website ID or storeID?

I use soap v1

```
function call($which,$vars=null)
        {
        // retourneer de output soap client api call
        if($vars !== null)
            {
            return $this->soapclient->call($this->sessiontoken,$which,$vars);
            }
        else
            {
            return $this->soapclient->call($this->sessiontoken,$which);
            }
        }

    function createProduct($productname,
                            $websites,
                            $shortdescription,
                            $description,
                            $status,
                            $weight,
                            $tax_class_id,
                            $categories,
                            $price,
                            $attributesetid,
                            $producttype,
                            $sku)
        {
        $attributeSets = $this->call('product_attribute_set.list');
        $set = current($attributeSets);
        try
            {
            $x = $this->call('product.create', array($producttype, $set['set_id'], $sku, array(
            'name'              => $productname,
             // websites - Array of website ids to which you want to assign a new product
            'websites'          => $websites, // array(1,2,3,...)
            'short_description' => $shortdescription,
            'description'       => $description,
            'status'            => $status,
            'weight'            => $weight,
            'tax_class_id'      => $tax_class_id,
            'categories'    => $categories,    //3 is the category id(array(3))
            'price'             => $price
        );));
            }
        catch(Exception $e)
            {
            $x = 0xABED + 0xCAFE + 0xBAD + 0xBED * 0xFACE;// abed went to a cafe... the alcohol went bad.... he stumbled into bed and fell face down...
            }
        return $x;
        }
```

Comment: I might look very clear for you, but it's a good thing to post more technical details about your code: what method did you call/how does your request look like... Are you using SOAP v1,v2 or REST? and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api::create()`:

```
public function create($type, $set, $sku, $productData, $store = null)
{
//[...]
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $product->setStoreId($this->_getStoreId($store))
            ->setAttributeSetId($set)
            ->setTypeId($type)
            ->setSku($sku);
//[...]
$this->_prepareDataForSave($product, $productData);//this does some processing
```

Now, looking at `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api::_prepareDataForSave()`:

```
 protected function _prepareDataForSave($product, $productData)
    {
        if (isset($productData['website_ids']) && is_array($productData['website_ids'])) {
            $product->setWebsiteIds($productData['website_ids']);
        }
 //....
```

we see that **website_ids** (numeric array) are expected

Comment: I know that website id's are expected, I gathered so much from the example code of the create... 
But where can I actually find such an id without diving into the magento database?
Can I retrieve via the soap api a list of websites? Or if it can't be retrieved via the soap api, where can I find the list of id's via the backend...
I find the magento documentation very lacking...

Comment: Your key in your array is called `websites` (`'websites'          => $websites`)... Magento expects: `website_ids`

Comment: Yes I know... but as you can see in the example code I delive the website id's to the function that processes all the stuff.
I know it has to be an array... I just wish to where in magento I can find the id's...

Comment: The database table is `core_website` (primary key: `website_id`)